# ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined Angular SSR

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am trying to build using command `npm run build:ssr` for my Angular application. Application built successfully done, But at the time of running command `npm run serve:ssr` I'm getting this error -

```
ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined
```

PS: As per my finding issue is with firebase package I am using. I wrapped the whole content under the check `if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {}` but still getting error.

Probably this line of import

```
import { openDb, deleteDb } from 'idb';
```

is causing issue, can anyone help.
Do I need to import `idb` dynamically?

PPS: I have already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092429/referenceerror-idbindex-is-not-defined-in-angular-universal-app) answer but not working for me

Comment: Does that help? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1797#issuecomment-498474850

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the firebase package to the latest version. ( Not AngularFire)

```
npm i firebase@9.6.10
```

[ First remove firebase from package.json and run `npm i` . Check your package.lock.json to ensure that it is also deleted from there- if not manually delete].